# How to insert URL in IMPORTRANGE() in spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm unable to figure out how to insert URL in the IMPORTRANGE(). What do we consider as the **range_string** (which is the second argument of the IMPORTRANGE)

Answer (score 0):

#### Usage:

```
IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet-url", "sheet-name!RangeStart:RangeEnd")
```

#### Example:

```
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcd123abcd123", "sheet1!A1:C10")
```

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTRANGE - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)